# ggplot2: saving plot as EPS with embedded font

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2

A journal wants me to submit the figures as EPS files. Exporting them as EPS file from R using ggplot2 and then opening the EPS file in Adobe Illustrator tells me "font not found on system".

How do I solve that problem? Here is the syntax I currently use.

```
library(ggplot2)    
a <-c("Sad Mood", "Cognition", "Fatigue", "Interest Loss", "Slowed", "Self-blame", "Suicidal Ideation", "Early insomnia", "Appetite", "Late insomnia", "Agitated", "Weight", "Middle insomnia", "Hypersomnia", "Age", "Sex")
b <-c(20.7,16.5,13.8,13.1,8.8,6.4,6.1,3.6,3.0,2.5,2.1,1.3,0.9,0.7,0.4,0.1)
c <-c(17.90,13.64,11.36,10.72,6.99,4.60,4.68,2.38,2.09,1.65,1.35,0.76,0.47,0.24,0.15,0.03) #lower CI
d <-c(23.47,19.27,16.28,15.74,10.64,8.20,7.95,5.07,4.21,3.63,2.99,2.22,1.59,1.62,0.95,0.31) #upper CI

data <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
data1 <- transform(data, a = reorder(a, order(b, decreasing = FALSE)))
data1$label <-sprintf("%.1f", data1$b)

ggplot(data1, aes(x=as.factor(a), y=b, order=a))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill='#888888',colour='#888888') +theme_bw() +coord_flip() +
  ylab("Relative importance estimation in %") +xlab("") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=c, ymax=d), width=.3, size=.5)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=label), size=4.5, vjust=.4,hjust=-1.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0, 25))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, vjust=-.2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an R package called [extrafont](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/index.html) which I used to solve a problem like this in the past. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Protonk/b54005de62b1513eda6a) is the solution I used.

Basically, there is a font database that R will use and a font database that postscript will use. Most of the time you won't have to do what I did above with lines 12-27, but if you have a font with a non-standard naming scheme you'll have to manually edit R's font database.

Your primary issue will be ensuring that the font name (and the font family name) are the same in R and PS. You should be able to do so by installing extrafont (installing it the first time builds the font database in R) and loading the fonts with the correct device.

Comment: This was a solution I found on google before I posted here; however, it is for PDF, not for EPS, and I couldn't get it to work with my script. What exactly are "loadfonts(device = "pdf"); loadfonts(device = "postscript")" for?

Comment: You may be better served by installing extrafont and looking at the docs, b/c I did this a few months ago. :) But loadfonts registers the font with the specified device (e.g. `pdf` or `postscript`). In this case we can specify a font in R, then register it in PS using extrafont. That *should* avoid the problem w/ fonts not being seen. If not, you'll have to make sure that the font name and family name match exactly, which sucks if you have font families w/ spaces + ggplot2. Sorry I can't remember more off the top of my head.